# Button appearing differently in AVD/Graphical layout and on a actual phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have modified my button to look like a spinner. On the AVD and Graphical layout it appears exactly like a spinner would but on my phone it appears quite different.

Button on the AVD:

[image]

Button on my phone:[image]

Can someone tell me why this is happening??

Here is the Button layout in XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/datebutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/datebuttontxt"
    android:onClick="datepicker"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Spinner" />
```

Changing the button background to invisible is not helping. 
**Also**, If I use an actual spinner it would appear correctly, just like it shows on the AVD.

Comment: What physical device do you have?

Comment: Manufacturers/carriers make proprietary changes to the Android OS that gets shipped on their phones. That can (and usually does) include changes to GUI elements like buttons, spinners, etc. Does this spinner graphic match other spinners used throughout the Galaxy S3?

Comment: Spinner appears as it should be, otherwise. Look at marmor's answer below...it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Widget.DeviceDefault.X` styles change between different devices, use `@android:style/Widget.Holo.X` styles to get a consistant look and feel.

In your case:

```
@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner
```

Comment: That did it. I was thinking in the same lines but was unable to find the right value for style. Thank you!